# How to change in wordpress the mobile navbar menu background color from transparent to indigo as soon as the menu button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

Using wordpress I have created a transparent navbar inside a photo with help of bs4navwalker (https://github.com/nicgene/bs4navwalker#bs4navwalker). In the desktop version it looks ok.
[image: navbar desktop version]

But in the mobile version the menu entries overlay with text on the page, after clicking on the navbar menu button.
[image: navbar mobile version]

I would like to change the background color of the menu to indigo as soon as somebody clicks on the mobile navbar menu button. The button itself should stay as it is, if it has not been clicked on it.

So far I have tried to find appropriate classes, in which I would like to change the properties via css, but I have not found the appropriate ones within the bs4navwalker.php file.

Inside the theme's header.php the navbar is declared:

```
<nav id='navbar_0' style="postion: relative;" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top indigo topBotomBordersIn">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu([
    'menu'            => 'primary',
    'theme_location'  => 'top',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_id'    => 'navbarCollapse',
    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'menu_id'         => false,
    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
    ]);
  ?>
</nav>
```

My css is

```
.indigo{
background:rgba(63,81,181,0.90); /* indigo, 4th value is alpha, better than opacity, which makes also the font transparent  */
color: white !important;  /* font color for transition */
transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;

.transparent{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);

.solid{
  background-color:rgba(63,81,181,0.75);  /* indigo */
  color: #ffffff !important;  /* font color */
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  }
```

And I applied the transparent class to the navbar only for one page of the web site via a javascript function navbar_transparent(). I also have applied a function navbar_animation(), which turns the navbar into a solid navbar as soon as the user has scrolled the page more than 25 pixels down.

```
function navbar_transparent(){
jQuery('.navbar').removeClass('indigo');
jQuery('.navbar').addClass('transparent');

function navbar_animation(){
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Transition effect for navbar
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  // checks if window is scrolled more given value, adds/removes solid class
  if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
    jQuery('.navbar').addClass('solid');
    }else{
     jQuery('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
    }
  });
});
}
```

Does somebody have a hint?

Comment: Assign the correct class using media queries. That way you don't need the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Gerard for the comment. I tried the media query `@media (max-width: 767px) { .navbar-collapse{background:rgba(63,81,181,1.0);}}`. This works, but I have also included a function navbar_animation() in my javascript, which turns the transparant navbar into indigo, after the user has scrolled more the 25 pixels down. This also affects the appearance of the non-collapsed mobile navbar button. I have included the code in the question above. Sorry for not submitting it in the beginning - I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I found an answer. It is based upon the demand that the nav element should have only one out of the three color classes at a moment: transparent, indigo or solid. Further, the function navbar_animation() has only an effect on the navbar, if the window is at least 768 pixels wide, due to a media query. In other words, in mobile view the navbar_function has no effect. This is accomplished by modified javascript functions:

```
function navbar_transparent(){
  jQuery('.navbar').removeClass('indigo');
  jQuery('.navbar').addClass('transparent');
  jQuery('.navbar-toggler').click(function(){  // navbar should have only one of the three color classes: transparent, solid, indigo
      var el = document.getElementById('navbar_0');
    if(el.classList.contains('transparent')){
      jQuery('nav').removeClass('transparent');
      jQuery('nav').addClass('solid');  // switch to solid
      }
    else if(el.classList.contains('indigo')){
      jQuery('nav').removeClass('indigo');
      jQuery('nav').addClass('solid');  // switch to solid
      }
    else if(el.classList.contains('solid')){
      jQuery('nav').removeClass('solid');
      jQuery('nav').addClass('transparent');  // switch back to transparent
    }    
  })
}
function navbar_animation(){
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Transition effect for navbar
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
      // checks if window is scrolled more given value, adds/removes solid class
      var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)") // perform transition to indigo navbar only, if in desktop view
      if(x.matches){
        var el = document.getElementById('navbar_0');
        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 25){  // if scrolled enough, make navbar indigo
          if(el.classList.contains('transparent')){
            jQuery('.navbar').removeClass('transparent');
            jQuery('.navbar').addClass('indigo');
            }
          }
        else{
          if(el.classList.contains('indigo')){  // if scrolled up again, switch back to transparent navbar
            jQuery('.navbar').removeClass('indigo');
            jQuery('.navbar').addClass('transparent');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this solution:

Add the filter in your functions.php.

```
function device_body_class ( $classes ) 
{
   $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
   $mobile = $detect->isMobile();
   $tablet = $detect->isTablet();
   if ( $mobile ) {
        $classes[] = 'mobile';
        if ( $tablet ) {
            $classes[] = 'tablet';
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'phone';
        }
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'desktop';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'device_body_class' );
```

And then in your style.css, you can have something like :

```
.desktop .my-navbar-class{
 // do whatever
}
.mobile .my-navbar-class{
 // do whatever
}
 
.tablet .my-navbar-class{
 // do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ Mohammed Yassine CHABLI for the answer. In the end I needed a media query. I did it via a query of the window width, `min-width: 768px`, which was sufficient for my purrpose. See my answer to my question.

Comment: Your welcome, there is a lot of solution to resolve that.